# Generators of the symmetric square of the group ring of an abelian group

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-cohomology

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $R=\mathbb{Z}[A]$- its group ring. Denote by $I$ an ideal of $R$ given by a kernel of the map $R\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus A,$ sending $[r]$ to $(1,r)$. Next, denote by $\mathbb{S}^2 I$ the symmetric square of $I$ as an abelian group, tensored with $\mathbb{Q}$.

I claim that the elements $([a]+[b]-[c]-[d])^2$ with $ab=cd$ generate $\mathbb{S}^2 I$. This fact is an obvious consequence of the following identity:

$2([a]+[b]-[ab]-[1])\otimes([c]+[d]-[cd]-[1])+$
$2([c]+[d]-[cd]-[1])\otimes([a]+[b]-[ab]-[1])=$
$([ab]+[cd]-[bd]-[ac])^2+([ab]+[cd]-[ad]-[bc])^2-([bd]+[ac]-[ad]-[bc])^2-
([a]+[bd]-[d]-[ab])^2-([ad]+[b]-[ab]-[d])^2+ ([a]+[bd]-[ad]-[b])^2
 - ([a]+[bc]-[c]-[ab])^2 - ([ac]+[b]-[ab]-[c])^2 + ([a]+[bc]-[ac]-[b])^2
 - ([c]+[ad]-[a]-[cd])^2-([ac]+[d]-[cd]-[a])^2+([c]+[ad]-[ac]-[d]) ^2-
 ([c]+[bd]-[b]-[cd])^2- ([bc]+[d]-[cd]-[b])^2+ ([c]+[bd]-[bc]-[d])^2+2([a]+[b]-[ab]-[1])^2 + 2 ([c]+[d] -[cd]-[1])^2.
$

**Question 1**
Does this fact have any nice interpretation? Is there a non-computational proof?
**Question 2**
Is it true that elements  $([a]+[b]-[c]-[d])^h$ with $ab=cd$ generate $\mathbb{S}^h I$ for $h>2$?

Comment: Nice result! Is the $+$ in $a+b$ the same operation as the tacit $\cdot$ in $ad$ ? I suggest getting into the habit of always declaring an abelian group to be either additive or multiplicative :)

Comment: Thanks! I've also renamed one of the two $d$s in your Question 2 as an $h$, so that the other can enjoy its private space.